# IOS Scenekit: rotate node to look at another node

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit

I want to rotate my camera to some object or point in my scene. I know that for this job it can be used a specific LookAt Constrait, but I want, that my "z" angle always been zero

Do you have any ideas?

Input data: camera position and target position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the constraint's `gimbalLockEnabled` property to `YES`